# Problems sharing object instance with mocha.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, supertest

I've been struggling for a couple hours with this problem and I just can't find a solution.

Lets say I have this file(**main.js**) exporting an object:

```
var MyModule = require('./module');
var dependency = require('./moduleDependency');

exports.start = function start(app){
    var myObject = new MyModule(dependency);

    module.exports.myObject = myObject; //sharing this object
};
```

And then, in a controller I require it (**controller.js**) modifying that object:

```
var myObject = require('./main').myObject;

exports.routeLogic = function(req, res, next){
    myObject.setName('newName');
    res.sendStatus(200);
};
```

the problem is in my test-spec when I require **myObject**, those modifications are missing:

```
var myObject = require('./main').myObject;

describe('test spec', function(){
    before(function(done){
        //executing request in order to use that controller
    });
    it('should pass', function(){
        res.name.should.equal('newName');
    });
});
```

I'm using **supertest** and **mocha** for this tests

Thanks in advance ;]

Comment: As I undestand, for `myObject` to be defined and changed `start()` and `routeLogic()` functions should be called? Are you sure that they are called?

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev I'm positive. I think this is a problem related to how Mocha works because this has no sense